# Codeigniter preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, preg-replace, regex-group

I am not sure if this problem is a boo-boo on my part or something about CI. I have a preg_replace process to convert a published gdoc spreadsheet url back into the original spreadsheet url.

```
$pat ='/(^[a-z\/\.\:]*?sheet\/)(pub)([a-zA-Z0-9\=\?]*)(\&output\=html)/';
$rep ='$1ccc$3#gid=0';

$theoriginal = preg_replace( $pat, $rep, $published );
```

This works fine in a test page run locally. This test page isn't framed by CI - it's just a basic php page.

When I copy and paste the pattern and replacement into the CI view which it's intended for, no joy.

Is this malfunction caused by CI or my 'bad' ? Are there easy-to-implement remedies ?

Here's a bit more code from the CI view:

```
    <body id="sites" >

<?php 

foreach ( $dets as $item )
{
    $nona = $item->nona;
    $address = $item->address;
    $town = $item->town;
    $pc = $item->pc;
    $foto1 = $item->foto1;
    $foto1txt = $item->foto1txt;
    $foto2 = $item->foto2;
    $foto2txt = $item->foto2txt;
    $costurl = $item->costurl;
    $sid = $item->sid;
}

//convert published spreadsheet url to gdoc spreadsheet url
$pat ='/(^[a-z\/\.\:]*?sheet\/)(pub)([a-zA-Z0-9\=\?]*)(\&output\=html)/i';
$rep ='$1ccc$3#gid=0';

$spreadsheet = preg_replace( $pat, $rep, $costurl);
```

Tom

Comment: Could it be CI's allowed URI characters? I'm not sure how are you accessing the file, etc... but check that.

Comment: Then it's not CI, what does the var_dump show for each variable?

Comment: var_dump shows the effect of the preg_replace is exactly nothing: $theorignal === $published. Zilch.

Comment: well it's just a CI view page w the bit of code above leafed into it: there's nothing special abt it and it's quite long.

Comment: i've added a bt more code but not sure if it casts any light...

Comment: I have solved it. I worked on the pattern to simplify it. It was lame tho seemed to work locally. I pruned it down and lo' it functions at home and in the wild. Thanks for your input. Not a great question but still it's taught me something.

Comment: Last word: the preg_replace pattern which I arrived at which seems to work is : $pattern ="/(^.*?sheet\/)pub(.*)(\&[a-z\=]*$)/";
$replacement ="$1ccc$2#gid=0"; ....this works as a way to convert a published spreadsheet url back into a gdoc spreadsheet

Comment: @Tom: Feel free to post your answer and mark it as "accepted" for the benefit of future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you came to can be "tidied" up a bit:

```
~^(.*?sheet/)pub(.*)(&[a-z=]*)$~
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AlG0k4/1).

The leading `^` and trailing `$` are not usually put inside the groups. The `/` can be left unescaped if you use a regex delimiter other than `/`. A `&` and `=` are not special regex metacharacters, `=` is only "special" in positive lookaround constructs. So, your pattern means:

- `^` - start of a string  anchor
- `(.*?sheet/)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible (and since I belive the point is to only match `pub` in the URL path, not the query string, you need to actually replace `.*?` with `[^?#]*?` negated character class matching 0+ chars other than `#` and `?`), up to the first occurrence of `sheet/` and the subsequent subpatterns...
- `pub` - a substring
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, up to the last occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns...
- `(&[a-z=]*)` - Group 3: a `&` followed with 0 or more ASCII letters  (since `i` modifier is  used, the `[a-z]` pattern will also match uppercase letters) and/or `=`
- `$` - end of string anchor.

It seems to me that you may also use a better pattern like

```
~^([^?#]*?sheet/)pub(.*)(&[a-z=]*)$~
   ^^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AlG0k4/2). Explanation of the change is provided in the explanation above.